# Is there any functional purpose to specify type = text for input elements?

Tags: html, css, forms

I some times see this form:

```
  <input type="text"></input>
```

However; as this is the default as seen on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input), is there any reason to state it explicitly?

Comment: I rarely use it myself and never had a problem.

Comment: What if you want to select only *text*-inputs with CSS or JS?

Comment: @user17791008 ... If you omit the attribute there is no straightforward way to select just text-inputs anymore. You would have to add some other attribute or (even worse) explicitly exclude all other input types you do not want to select (e.g. `input:not([type=checkbox])`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately ...

Although it is the default, if you do not explicitly state it in the HTML then the selector:

```
input[type=text]{
}
```

will not work.